# Where can I find opencl dll for old intel video cards?

Tags: windows, opencl

Early there was some installer with opencl.dll but intel has changed website and now I can't find it.

I don't even need it to detect gpu device and work, I just need interfaces but what is correct source for opencl on windows if I have some very old intel gpu?

generally I think I need CPU version

Comment: Which GPU model? Windows?

Comment: @harrymc Intel(R) G45/G43 Express

Comment: Instead of submitting a comment please edit your question

Answer (score 0):

You can find them [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers) with support for OpenCL 2.0.

AMD’s [GPU-drivers](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) include the OpenCL-drivers for CPUs, APUs and GPUs, version 2.0.

NVIDIA’s [GPU-drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) mention mostly CUDA, but the drivers for OpenCL 1.2 are there too.